# Difference between functions generating random numbers in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am trying to understand what is the difference, if any, between these functions:

```
numpy.random.rand()

numpy.random.random()

numpy.random.uniform()
```

It seems that they produce a random sample from a uniform distribution. So, without any parameter in the function, is there any difference?

Answer (score 8):

[`numpy.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=None)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) - uniform samples from arbitrary range

> Draw samples from a uniform distribution.
>   Samples are uniformly distributed over the half-open interval `[low, high)` (includes low, but excludes high). In other words, any value within the given interval is equally likely to be drawn by uniform.

[`numpy.random.random(size=None)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html) - uniform distribution between 0 and 1

> Return random floats in the half-open interval `[0.0, 1.0)`.
>   Results are from the “continuous uniform” distribution over the stated interval. To sample `Unif[a, b)`, `b > a` multiply the output of `random_sample by` (b-a) and add a:
>   `(b - a) * random_sample() + a`

[`numpy.random.rand(d0, d1, ..., dn)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html) - Samples from a uniform distribution to populate an array of a given shape

> Random values in a given shape.
>   Create an array of the given shape and propagate it with random samples from a uniform distribution over `[0, 1)`.

To answer your other question, given all default parameters all of the functions `numpy.random.uniform`, `numpy.random.random`, and `numpy.random.rand` are identical.

Comment: On a side note, all of the functions in `numpy.random` populate an array rather than create a single value (if no shape is specified, they return a single value).  The main difference between `np.random.rand` and `np.random.random` is in how the shape of the array is specified.  `data = np.random.random([10, 10])` instead of `data = np.random.rand(10, 10)`.

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer

Without parameters, the three functions are equivalent, producing a random float in the range [0.0,1.0).

### Details

`numpy.random.rand` is a convenience function that accepts an arbitrary number of parameters as dimensions. It's different from the other `numpy.random` functions, `numpy.zeros`, and `numpy.ones` also, in that all of the others accept shapes, i.e. N-tuples (specified as Python lists or tuples). The following two lines produce identical results (the random seed notwithstanding):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random_sample((1,2,3)) # a single tuple as parameter
x = np.random.rand(1,2,3) # integers as parameters
```

`numpy.random.random` is an alias for `numpy.random.random_sample`.

`numpy.random.uniform` allows you to specify the limits of the distribution, with the `low` and `high` keyword parameters, instead of using the default [0.0,1.0).

Comment: `numpy.random.rand` was designed to mimic MATLAB's `rand` function which, incidentally, now also accepts shapes as arguments.