# (psuedo) Randomly generated Matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-interactive

I want to create a matrix using the following arrays:

```
A = [1111,2222,3333]
B = [20,25,26,27]
C = [1.5,2.6,3.7,4.5,5.4,6.7,7.2,8.8,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.2]
```

Each value in A need to be mapped to all values in be once (each element in A will be attached to all four values in b) and from there, I want the resulting 12,2 matrix to become a 12,3 matrix by adding array C

It should look like the following:

```
1111 20 1.5
1111 25 2.6
1111 26 3.7    
1111 27 4.5
2222 20 5.4
2222 25 6.7
2222 26 7.2
2222 27 8.8
...........
3333 27 12.2
```

My first idea is to use a couple for loops, but I'm having a lot of trouble implementing the values in the 1st column

In my actual code the values will be assign as follows:

```
A = [random.randint(1250,14180) for x in range(len(5))]
C = [round(random.uniform(1.0,4.0),1) for x in range(len(15))]
```

B will be non random

```
B = [2000,2500,2600,2700]
```

Comment: where is it random? if it has fixed number in input? you should use random(https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

Comment: For the first part you can use itertools.product, but I see nothing random here, so it's hard to be sure that's what you need.

Comment: I just gave some example arrays, but when I make them in my code there I use random.randint() to make the values in A , B, C

Comment: I'll make the edits to show what I'll be using

Comment: You should show exactly your purpose. Why you need to create this type of matrix, precise example(shorter will be better). Example a= [1,2,3] b=[4,5,6] I want : [[1,2,3][4,5,6]]

Comment: I just finished editing, let me know if this helps. Sorry for being unclear before, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `itertools` package

```
import itertools

A = [1111,2222,3333]
B = [20,25,26,27]
C = [1.5,2.6,3.7,4.5,5.4,6.7,7.2,8.8,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.2]

# create the product of A and B, i.e., [(1111,20), (1111,25), ..., (3333,27)]
AB = itertools.product(A,B)

# zip with C
ABC = itertools.izip( AB, C )

# flatten sublists, since ABC is an iterator for [((1111,20),1.5), ..., ((3333,27),12,2)]
ABC = [ list(ab)+[c] for ab,c in ABC ]

print ABC
```

which gives

```
[[1111, 20, 1.5],
 [1111, 25, 2.6],
 [1111, 26, 3.7],
 [1111, 27, 4.5],
 [2222, 20, 5.4],
 [2222, 25, 6.7],
 [2222, 26, 7.2],
 [2222, 27, 8.8],
 [3333, 20, 9.0],
 [3333, 25, 10.0],
 [3333, 26, 11.0],
 [3333, 27, 12.2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at :

```
weights_h = [[random.random() for e in inputs[0]] for e in range(hiden_neurons)]
```

But really, you should probably use numpy.

```
In [9]: numpy.random.random((3, 3))
Out[9]:
array([[ 0.37052381,  0.03463207,  0.10669077],
       [ 0.05862909,  0.8515325 ,  0.79809676],
       [ 0.43203632,  0.54633635,  0.09076408]])
```

From:

[Simple way to create matrix of random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451958/simple-way-to-create-matrix-of-random-numbers)