# How can we populate a matrix with 1 or 0 randomly in one line in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I wrote a code to populate a matrix with 0 or 1 randomly. But it ended in 4-5 lines. I want it to be in 1 line.

```
pop_size = (8,10)
initial_pop = np.empty((pop_size))
for i in range(pop_size[0]):
     for j in range(pop_size[1]):
          initial_pop[i][j] = rd.randint(0,1)
```

Comment: Can you explain more clearly, not understanding your question?

Comment: `np.random.randint()`?  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html

Comment: Use [randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html)

Comment: `np.random.randint(2, (8, 10))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use numpy's `randint` method

```
matrix = np.random.randint(2, size=pop_size)
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are using `NumPy`. If so, then the answer is:

```
np.random.randint(2, size=pop_size)
```

Here is NumPy docs article on this routine: [LINK](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html).
Numpy is well-documented, next time try checking the docs yourself.

edit: the argument should be 2, not 1

Comment: Having `1` won't work. Needs to be `2` for the first argument. Otherwise you'll get `0`s everywhere.

Comment: @hqkhan you're right. It's inconsistent with python's `random.randint` whose upper bound is inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

In standard Python, try:

```
from random import randint
x = [[randint(0,1) for _ in range(8)] for _ in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer on : [Simple way to create matrix of random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451958/simple-way-to-create-matrix-of-random-numbers)

you can easily populate a matrix using numPy.

e.g:

3x3 matrix :

```
import numpy as np
my_matrix = np.random.randint(2,size=3)

output = ([[0,1,0],
          [0,0,1],
          [1,0,1]])
```

documentation:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html?highlight=randint#numpy.random.randint

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only 1 or 0 in your array you can do so by following.

```
    import numpy as np
    np.zeros(2,2) #it will create [2,2] matrix with all zeros
    np.ones(2,2)  #it will create [2,2] matrix with all ones
```