# Simple way to create matrix of random numbers of x,y size where the sum of each col and rows is equal to z

Tags: python

hi i would like for the game of quantum werewolf to generate a matrix of x,y size where the sum is equal to Z

and x = y

Here is what i would like to obtain :

example : x=3 , y=3 z=1

```
[0.1,0.2,0.7] = 1
[0.5,0.3,0.2] = 1
[0.4,0.5,0.1] = 1
  1   1   1
```

here is what i tried but this code is false:

```
import numpy as np

def generate_matrix(x, y, z):
    matrix = np.random.rand(x, y)
    row_sums = matrix.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
    col_sums = matrix.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)
    matrix = matrix / row_sums * z

    # Verify that the sum of each row is equal to Z
    assert np.allclose(matrix.sum(axis=1), z), "Row sums are not equal to Z"

    # Verify that the sum of each column is equal to Z
    assert np.allclose(matrix.sum(axis=0), z), "Column sums are not equal to Z"

    return matrix.round(2)

x = 3
y = 3
z = 1

result_matrix = generate_matrix(x, y, z)
print(result_matrix)
```

i've looked on this question :

[Simple way to create matrix of random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451958/simple-way-to-create-matrix-of-random-numbers)

regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple way to create matrix of random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451958/simple-way-to-create-matrix-of-random-numbers)

Comment: there is no the validation condition of the sum

Comment: This is not possible if `x != y` and `z != 0`. For example, let `x = 1, y = 2, z = 4`, resulting in a matrix like `[[a, b]]`; if `a + b = 4`, then `a != 4` or `b != 4`. More formally, if each row sums to `z`, then sum of the matrix is `xz`; and if each column sums to `z`, then the sum of the matrix is `yz`. A matrix can't have two different sums, so `xz = yz`, which is only possible if `z = 0` or `x = y`.

Comment: @Amadan yes x will equal y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an iterative mechanism to generate this matrix:

```py
import numpy as np

def generate_matrix(x, y, z, max_iters=10):
    matrix = np.random.rand(x, y)

    for _ in range(max_iters):
        matrix /= matrix.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
        matrix *= z
        matrix /= matrix.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)
        matrix *= z

    assert np.allclose(matrix.sum(axis=1), z), "Row sums are not equal to Z"
    assert np.allclose(matrix.sum(axis=0), z), "Column sums are not equal to Z"

    return matrix.round(2)
```